# MYSQL: create an insert with data from two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I know i can use a subquery to make an insert after selecting rows from the database.

```
INSERT INTO wp_43_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT ID, 8363, 0 FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT
wp_43_posts.ID
FROM
wp_43_posts
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_relationships ON wp_43_term_relationships.object_id = wp_43_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_taxonomy ON wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_43_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE  (wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 4613 OR wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 4615) AND wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id != 8363 ) posts
```

But what if, instead of hardcoding 8363, i'd need to derive it from another query?For example I'd need to deriv it from

```
SELECT
wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
FROM
wp_43_term_taxonomy
WHERE
wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 8363
```

Comment: Looks like you have several hardcoded values here ; maybe it's time to consider generating a .sql file containing your INSERT queries from a simple script (whatever being your preferred language for that, PHP, Python etc), allowing to retrieve values into variables before binding them to queries, prepare arrays of identifiers to use in loops...

Comment: @FrostyZ it would take 2 minutes to make a wp cli command, you are right, but i have to use mysql because sometimes it's easier. And i was curious. I could have simply run the other query and hardcoded the value but wanted to know how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the constant with the second query in ()'s, it should work.
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_43_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id,term_order)
SELECT ID,
(SELECT wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_43_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 8363),
0 FROM
... remaining of the original ...
```

At least if you need only 1 value, otherwise it would be better to join this extra table to the others.

Answer (score 1):

just bring it into the subquery and use an extra join:

```
INSERT INTO wp_43_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT ID, someval, 0 FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT
wp_43_posts.ID,t.term_taxonomy_id someval
FROM
wp_43_posts
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_relationships ON wp_43_term_relationships.object_id = wp_43_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_taxonomy ON wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_43_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE  (wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 4613 OR wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id = 4615) AND wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id != 8363 
join wp_43_term_taxonomy t on t.term_id = 8363 ) posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, see modified query below. Essentially include that column into subquery select clause you want to make for `INSERT` statement. Also, you certainly don't need that condition `AND wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id != 8363`

```
INSERT INTO wp_43_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT ID, term_id, 0 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
wp_43_posts.ID, 
wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id
FROM wp_43_posts
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_relationships 
ON wp_43_term_relationships.object_id = wp_43_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_43_term_taxonomy 
ON wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_43_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_43_term_taxonomy.term_id IN(4613, 4615) posts
```